# QAudioDecoder format() Causes Crash

Tags: c++, c, qt

I have the following code,

```
audio_decoder->setAudioFormat(*audio_format);   // audio_decoder is QAudioDecoder
audio_decoder->setSourceDevice(file);           // QFile
audio_decoder->start();

QAudioFormat *format = new QAudioFormat(audio_output->format());
```

Any attempt to perform

```
audio_output->format();
```

causes an immediate crash. Nothing else does this- not start(), read() etc. Is this a Qt bug, or am I doing something horribly, horribly wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: You might be doing something wrong, but from that small amount of code it cannot been seen. For example, is `audio_output` null?

Comment: No. It's declared as audio_decoder = new QAudioDecoder in the initialization, and the start() and read() functions worked, and the read function produced some output.

Comment: I asked about `audio_output`, not about `audio_decoder`.

Comment: Arg. It was meant to be audio_decoder! Thanks for pointing that out.